# Windows 8 Javascript app dropdown acting like a spinner on slate?

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I'm designing a windows 8 metro style app using javascript and I have a dropdown that populates with items.

On windows 8 it on my desktop it works like a normal dropdown.

On windows 8 on a slate if there's more than a couple of options it acts similar to a spinner - i.e. the options are in a loop and as you scroll down it starts from the beginning again.

This makes it a little confusing in my app.

Is there any way to disable this functionality and have it act like a regular dropdown?

Comment: Just as a note for anyone who might be wondering about this as well, it appears that the "spinner" feature is by microsoft design.  There does not appear to be a way to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a note for anyone who might be wondering about this as well, it appears that the "spinner" feature is by microsoft design. There does not appear to be a way to prevent it.